# JQuery Vertical Tabs - create additional link to tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using this script for jQuery Vertical Tabs.

http://www.scriptbreaker.com/javascript/script/JQuery-vertical-tab-menu

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").hover(function() {
    var curMenu=$(this);
    $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected");
    curMenu.addClass("selected");

    var index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
    $(".curvedContainer .tabcontent").css("display","none");
    $(".curvedContainer #tab_content_"+index).css("display","block");
});
});
</script>
```

Here's the HTML for the tabs (links)

```
<div class="tabscontainer">
 <div class="tabs">
     <div class="tab selected first" id="tab_menu_1">
         <div class="link">JavaScript</div>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab" id="tab_menu_2">
         <div class="link">CSS</div>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
     </div>
      <div class="tab last" id="tab_menu_3">
         <div class="link">JQuery</div>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create an additional link from within a tabs content to another tab.

So this way I can link to the next tab or the last tab, keeping the same functionality as the current tab links (no refresh)

This is my first question on stackoverflow and I've searched far and wide.

I really appreciate all the help. This is a great community.

UPDATE:

Okay, Here is an edit with my full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").click(function() {
    var curMenu=$(this);
    $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected");
    curMenu.addClass("selected");

    var index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
    $(".curvedContainer .tabcontent").css("display","none");
    $(".curvedContainer #tab_content_"+index).css("display","block");

});

});
</script>

<div class="curvedContainer">       

<div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_1" style="display:block">
<p>text</p> 
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_2">
<p>text</p>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_3">
<p>text</p>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_4"><h2 class="wwd_title">
<p>text</p> 
</div>  

</div>

<div class="tabscontainer">

<div class="tabs">         
<div class="tab selected first" id="tab_menu_1">             
<div class="link">Onefish</div>       
</div>         
<div class="tab" id="tab_menu_2">             
<div class="link">Twofish</div>                   
</div>         
<div class="tab" id="tab_menu_3">             
<div class="link">Redfish</div>         
</div>          
<div class="tab last" id="tab_menu_4">             
<div class="link">Bluefish</div>                     
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly please post the code that you have tried so far to achieve what you want to achieve. (The code you have posted is the Vertical tab menu code.)

Comment: As a sidenote, the correct script tag should look like `<script type="text/javascript">`. The language attribute is outdated and may not guarantee that your browser will use the latest version of JavaScript.

Comment: @neo108 Thanks. Full Code Added.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make links in the tab contents force the tabs to switch, it helps to understand what is happening under the hood to make them switch by default.

By default, mouseover events force the tabs to change; therefore, the solution is to override the default click event of the hyperlinks in question by binding an event to hyperlinks in the tab content:

**Include this code after the JavaScript code you showed in your question, inside the $(document).ready**:

```
$('.tabcontent').find('a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.tabs #' + $(this).attr("rel")).mouseover();
});
```

The event.preventDefault() prevents the hyperlinks from attempting to redirect to the page entered in the href attribute, and the rel attribute is used as a way to bind the hyperlink to the specific tab being linked to.

The rel attribute is used to get the value of the id of the tab so we can programmatically invoke its mouseover event, and switch tabs.

```
<div class="tabscontainer">
 <div class="tabs">
     <div class="tab selected first" id="tab_menu_1">
         <div class="link">JavaScript</div>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab" id="tab_menu_2">
         <div class="link">CSS</div>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
     </div>
      <div class="tab last" id="tab_menu_3">
         <div class="link">JQuery</div>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
     </div>          
</div>
    <div class="curvedContainer">
        <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_1" style="display:block">content for tab 1 <a href="#" rel="tab_menu_2"> tab2</a></div>
        <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_2">content for tab 2</div>
        <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_3">content for tab 3</div>
    </div>
```

In the HTML content for your tab, simply include the hyperlink as you normally would, using an href="#" and a rel attribute. The rel attribute must equal the id of the target tab, in this case, tab_menu_2.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Okay, so I Tried it, but to no avail. Perhaps I added the script addition improperly. Either way, I updated my question with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

**It Works as per your requirements**

Just add

```
        <div class="tabs">
             <div class="tab selected first" id="tab_menu_1">
                 <div class="link">JavaScript</div>
                 <div class="arrow"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

in any of the tab

Go to this link http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/ssR5f/

There is a similar tab in `3rd` tab through which we can jump to `1st` tab.

Comment: I get the concept of using the existing classes to stick a tab inside another, but that is not what I am looking to do. Thank you.